# Flutter Container Column is not aligning correclty

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, alignment

I simply would like to have a couple of `Containers` inside a `Column` but somehow I can not align them correctly... This is my setup:

```
child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ShimmerContainer(
                height: 50,
                width: 200,
              ),
              ShimmerContainer(
                height: 50,
                width: 200,
              ),
              ShimmerContainer(
                height: 50,
                width: 200,
              )
            ],
          ),
```

And somehow my `Containers` are all aligned in the center. The really weird thing is that if I wrap one of these `ShimmerContainers` inside a `Align` with `Alignment.centerLeft` **all** other containers are also aligning left. I have no idea why this happens.

This is my `ShimmerContainer`:

```
class ShimmerContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  final double borderRadius;

  const ShimmerContainer({
    this.height,
    this.width,
    this.borderRadius = 0,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Shimmer.fromColors(
      baseColor: Colors.grey[200]!,
      highlightColor: Colors.white,
      child: Container(
        height: height != null ? height!.scaled : null,
        width: width != null ? width!.scaled : null,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: white,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            borderRadius,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add an image the Ui you like to archive?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh the Containers should left align not center

Comment: yes they are left alingned on your code.

Comment: Did you check if the parent Column is aligned at the Start?

Comment: and what is ` height!.scaled`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh you can ignore the `scaled` . really weird behavior. Already ran `flutter clean` and restarted everything. No success

Answer (score 1):

**Ouput of your code**
I added background color to view properly.

[image: your result]

I think you should use `flutter clean` and run again. Else error is happening from parent side.Does it solve your issue?

Comment: that is really weird. The parent is a `CustomScrollView`. On my simulator it is centered..

Comment: are you using MultiSliver? can you add more about parent